# svn blame on a partial file

Tags: svn, blame

My xml file editor/manager executes

```
svn blame
```

to determine which elements are not committed in svn.  Since the files are so large, there is a major performance issue doing this.

How do I execute `svn blame` on only specific lines of the file?